# Keyboard hiding tableview cells containing textfields

Tags: swift, uitableview, keyboard

I have a uiviewcontroller that contains a uitableview, this uitableview is full of custom cells that contain a textfield.

This view in storyboard is loaded as a popover, so the behaviour is:

iPad - If the keyboard is loaded and the keyboard hides the current editing cell, the cell automatically moves up so it is visible, regardless of its position in the tableview

iPhone - It doesn't, the tableview dosn't move if the keyboard hides the cell.

Can anyone suggest an elegant way round this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue using Xcode 8.2.1, swift 3 with keyboard hiding `UITextView` when it `becomeFirstResponder()`, spent few hours to figure out what was the problem without any luck, finally created new test project with single `UITableViewController` and it worked, thereafter re-created the Table View Controller in storyboard -  cells started to scroll to allow space for keyboard which appears just below the designated text view  as expected...

perhaps something with wiring that prevented it from working properly

Answer (score 0):

You can use the table view method scrollToRowAtIndexPath

```
func scrollToRowAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: NSIndexPath,
           atScrollPosition scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition,
                   animated animated: Bool)
```

to scroll the table view when a text field becomes the first responder, for example:

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: 4, inSection: 0)
tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: true)
```

See the UITableView reference for further information
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW44

I hope this helps you. Feel free to ask if anything is unclear.

Comment: Unless I implemented it incorrectly, this didn't work if the cell was at the bottom of the list. Worked great if the cell was in the middle of the list but didn't work for the bottom 3 or 4

Comment: Did you try setting the scroll position to .Top?

Comment: i did, on both top and bottom the bottom cell stays stuck to the bottom of the tableview

Comment: I know it’s an old question but did you get any workable solution? Having the exact problem than you. The keyboard hides the last cell of the table and scrolling doesn’t help.